# Angular flex MediaObserver and ObservableMedia import issue

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I just upgraded to Angular 10 along with the angular flex

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "10.0.0-beta.32",
```

I was using

```
import { ObservableMedia } from "@angular/flex-layout";
```

but now this is showing

```
Module '"../../../node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex-layout"' has no exported member 'ObservableMedia'.
```

From this https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/989, someone commented

> ObservableMedia was deprecated in 7.0.0-beta.19 and removed in
> 7.0.0-beta.23. Please use the nearly identical MediaObserver instead and consult the docs and CHANGELOG

so I tried `MediaObserver`

still the same issue. Any help

Answer (score 0):

There was no coding error but the cache issue. Restarting my IDE worked and resolved the dependencies.